# What to use in test? Show or ShowDialog?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a test for a Windows Forms User Control using Nunit and NCrunch. I want the test to do something like this:

```
<Test()> _
<TestCase("1")> _
<TestCase("2")> _
Public Sub Test(Value As String)
    Dim CtlObj As MyUserControl
    Using FormObj = New TEST_Form()
        CtlObj = New MyUserControl()
        CtlObj.Text = Value
        FormObj.Controls.Add(CtlObj)
        FormObj.Show()
        ' So test user can see the form.
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5)
        Assert.That(...)
    End Using
End Sub
```

The above code shows the form but the area containing the user control is transparent and I see the images behind the form.

I've tried: Refresh, SuspendLayout & ResumeLayout. I've not found anything which will display the user control.

If I use ShowDialog the user control is displayed but of course the code waits for the user to click on something to close the form.

I want my test to run automatically w/o needing user action.

I updated my test code to use a BackgroundWorker. The BackgroundWorkder calls ShowDialog. The main code sleeps for several seconds and then closes the BackgroundWorker which shuts down the form.

But using a backgroundworker seems clunky.

Is there a way to show the form and usercontrol w/o the backgroundworker

Comment: What is the intention of that test?

Comment: UI requires a message loop, Application.Run().  None of this is particularly friendly in a unit test, google "coded ui test" to get ahead.